# How to track limit usage over time

Tags: apex, limits

I am trying to develop a way that will allow our company to track our usage of various limited resources over time and then store those on a custom object.  In short I am looking to track things like total number of custom objects, license counts/usage, data storage usage, workflow rules, total number of apex characters.

Any links to the methods to call for all these different counts would help.

I know the calls to get the current usage are going to be in different methods (I know for instance that I can see the object counts from GlobalDescribe) but is there a way to query the **limit** in the specific org as well?

Comment: Support is quite limited for querying any limits beyond those which are transactional.